# QFileInfo size() is returning shortcut TARGET size

Tags: c++, qt, shortcut-file, qfileinfo

I am scanning folder size like this:

```
qint64 dirSize = 0;
int fileCount = 0;

for(QDirIterator itDir(someDir, QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::Files|QDir::Hidden|QDir::System,
                       QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    itDir.hasNext(); )
{
    itDir.next();
    dirSize += itDir.fileInfo().size();
    ++fileCount;
}
```

This appears to work fine.

However, I noticed that a folder containing Windows shortcuts (`.lnk`) is returning a much larger size than expected. The reason is that the sizes of the shortcut targets are being returned, rather than the sizes of the shortcut files themselves.

But according to [QFileInfo documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#details):

> On Windows, symlinks (shortcuts) are .lnk files. The reported size() is that of the symlink (not the link's target) [...]

**So my question is: what am I doing wrong here? How do I get the size of the shortcut file?**

Comment: Is this really a .lnk file? Perhaps you are using a different kind of shortcut.

Comment: Yes, these are definitely Windows shortcut (`.lnk`) files.

Comment: In those cases where `itDir` *should* refer to a link, what is returned by `itDir.filePath()` (or `itDir.fileInfo().filePath()`) -- is it the path of the link itself or the path of the target?

Comment: Both return the path of the link itself as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rob's answer works in most cases, but returns 0 when the the shortcut's target doesn't exist/is invalid.
Taking a cue from that approach, you can also copy the shortcut and change the extension.

So combining it all into a function (I'm assuming here that opening the target is cheaper/safer than copying the shortcut):

```
qint64 getFileSize(const QString &path)
{
    qint64 size = 0;
    QFileInfo fileInfo(path);

    if(fileInfo.isSymLink() && fileInfo.size() == QFileInfo(fileInfo.symLinkTarget()).size())
    {
        // Try this approach first
        QFile file(path);
        if(file.exists() && file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            size = file.size();
        file.close();

        // If that didn't work, try this
        if(size == 0)
        {
            QString tmpPath = path+".tmp";
            for(int i=2; QFileInfo().exists(tmpPath); ++i) // Make sure filename is unique
                tmpPath = path+".tmp"+QString::number(i);

            if(QFile::copy(path, tmpPath))
            {
                size = QFileInfo(tmpPath).size();
                QFile::remove(tmpPath);
            }
        }
    }
    else size = fileInfo.size();

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For testing purposes I created a shortcut of one of the Qt's DLL files. I placed this shortcut into an empty folder. I also created a shortcut of Qt's sdktool.exe and placed this into the same folder.

I also noticed that the size() returns the size of the actual file and not the size of shortcut. I remember I had somewhat similiar behaviour in my old project and what I did was that I opened the file before reading the size.

```
for (QDirIterator itr(someDir, QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::Files|QDir::Hidden|QDir::System,
                      QDirIterator::Subdirectories); itr.hasNext();) {
    itr.next();

    // Shows wrong size
    qDebug() << itr.fileName() << ", size (unopened): " << itr.fileInfo().size();

    QFile file(itr.filePath());
    if (file.exists() && file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        // Now the size shows correctly
        qDebug() << "Size when opened: " << file.size();
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
"sdktool.lnk" , size (unopened):  2817024
Size when opened:  1325
"test.lnk" , size (unopened):  4429312
Size when opened:  951
```

Windows 10's File Property window shows that the size of "test.lnk" is 951 bytes and the size of "sdktool.lnk" is 1325 bytes.

Comment: Cool, this seems to work. I've implemented this, but first I check if `itr.fileInfo().isSymLink()` and then if `file.size() == 0` I add `itr.fileInfo().size()` anyway.

Comment: Good catch! I forgot that `QFileInfo::isSymLink()` exists :)

Comment: I've found that this approach doesn't work for shortcuts with an invalid/nonexistant target. It will return 0 in both cases.